# How to use post variables in a constructor?

Tags: php

I have a class constructor that looks like the following (I left some of the variables out), however I don't know how to construct an object and also post variables to it. I inherited this code, so I know it works but not sure how ... can someone please tell me what is going on here? How can I create an object and set all those parameters?

```
function __construct()
{
$some variables set here 
 $user_name  = isset($_POST['user_name']) ? prepare_input($_POST['user_name'], true) : '';
    $password  = isset($_POST['password']) ? prepare_input($_POST['password'], true) : '';
//some more post variables

$this->wrongLogin = false;      
    if(!$this->IsLoggedIn()){
        if($submit_login == 'login'){
            if(empty($user_name) || empty($password)){
                if(isset($_POST['user_name']) && empty($user_name)){
                    $this->loginError = '_USERNAME_EMPTY_ALERT';                        
                }else if(isset($_POST['password']) && empty($password)){
                    $this->loginError = '_WRONG_LOGIN';
                }
                $this->wrongLogin = true;                           
            }else{
                $this->DoLogin($user_name, $password, $remember_me);
            }
        }else{
            if(isset($_COOKIE[$this->cookieName])){
                parse_str($_COOKIE[$this->cookieName]);
                if(!empty($type) && !empty($usr) && !empty($hash)){
                    $this->accountType = $type;
                    $user_name = $usr;
                    $password = $this->Decrypt($hash, $this->passwordKey);                  
                    $this->DoLogin($user_name, $password, '2');
                }
            }               
        }
    }else if($submit_logout == 'logout'){
        $this->DoLogout();
    }
```

Comment: You should not have any problem using $_POST variables in your constructors. What problem do you have?

Comment: How can I construct an object and set the post variables when those parameters aren't part of the constructor definition?

Comment: $_POST are global, they are part of your constructors and everything else.

Comment: Ah very simple, thanks so much!

Comment: Just posted an example of it in my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_POST variables can be accessed from any constructor, example :

```
<?php
class my_class {
  public $status;      // PROPERTY.
  public $user;        // PROPERTY.
  public $pass;        // PROPERTY.
function __construct ()
{ $this->user = ( isset( $_POST["user"] ) ) ? $_POST["user"] : ""; // PROPERTY.
  $this->pass = ( isset( $_POST["pass"] ) ) ? $_POST["pass"] : ""; // PROPERTY.
  if ( ( strlen( $this->user ) == 0 ) ||
       ( strlen( $this->pass ) == 0 ) )
       $this->status = false;  // PROPERTY.
  else $this->status = true;   // PROPERTY.
}  
}

$myc = new my_class();
$_POST["user"] = "abc"; // HERE $_POST VARIABLES ARE DEFINED AFTER
$_POST["pass"] = "123"; // THE CLASS IS BEEN INSTANTIATED.
if ( $myc->status )
     echo "Good";
else echo "Bad";
?>
```

It will display "Bad" because the $_POST variables did not exist when the class was instantiated, so the constructor assigned "" to the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the problem here, but you can do like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public $var1;
    public $var2;

    function __construct($var1, $var2 = 5){
        $this->var1 = $var;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
    }
}
```

somewhere in your code

```
// we can skip passing 2nd parameter
$myObject = new MyClass(10);
```

Comment: Like I said, I'm not sure how the post variables are being filled. I know I can make a constructor with all the variables I need, but this should work for my purposes as well, I just don't understand how I can construct an object and also fill the post variables so it can do the methods in the constructor.

Comment: Basically what I don't want to do is alter the code in any way, it is working without the params in the constructor declaration so I want to keep it that way.

Comment: @NickCabrera it takes 2 values from POST array user_name and password, I guess the object of this class should be created after user fill in sign in form. But, to understant how IsLoggedIn and other functions work you should show us full class